# Carte de Sejour - Validity after leaving France

Tags: resident-permit, france, residence-cards

I understand similar questions have been asked before but I'd be grateful for any response specific to my circumstances.

I'm from a non-EU country (Asian).
I hold a Carte de Sejour (Passeport Talent: Salarie en Mission) valid till 2022.
I left France and will be returning after a year of leaving to marry my French fiance.

My questions:
1. Is my carte de sejour still valid to use to enter France for the wedding? Or do I need to apply for a separate visa?
I'm unable to find any info on the prefecture website on whether the carte gets invalid if I leave France.

2. Can I convert this carte de sejour (passeport talent) to a carte de sejour (familiale) after the wedding?

Comment: Should we assume that the Asian country of which you are a citizen is one whose citizens require visas for short visits to the Schengen area?

Comment: Yes we require visas for short visits.
The original plan was to get a tourist visa for the wedding (providing the wedding as the reason for travel with the required documentation). And then return to my country to get a long term visa.

Was hoping to convert my existing CDS to a CDS (familiaile) as it sounds simpler.

Comment: When did you leave France?

Comment: Apologies for the late response. Was travelling last week. I left in Jun2019 and plan to re-enter in Apr 2020. From my online research, I found that regardless of the visa situation, the CDS familial can be applied for only after 6months of marriage - doubt this conversion would work :(